# Convert a list of blank separated numbers to a list of floats

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list like following:

```
['0.0000    0.0012    0.0024    0.0037    0.0049', '0.0061    0.0073    0.0085    0.0097    0.0110', '0.0122    0.0134    0.0146    0.0158    0.0170', '1.0000']
```

I want to remove apostrophe, commas, and white space from it and append items to a a new list. Output should look like this:

```
[0.0000,0.0012,0.0024,0.0037,0.0049,0.0061,0.0073,0.0085,0.0097,0.0110,0.0122,0.0134,0.0146,0.0158,0.0170,1.0000]
```

This may be trivial task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple one-liner: `split` (without argument so it has the nice feature of taking *any* number of space chars as separator), flatten by 2 non-nested loops in list comprehension, convert to `float` at the same time:

```
a = ['0.0000    0.0012    0.0024    0.0037    0.0049', '0.0061    0.0073    0.0085    0.0097    0.0110', '0.0122    0.0134    0.0146    0.0158    0.0170', '1.0000']

result = [float(x) for e in a for x in e.split()]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[0.0, 0.0012, 0.0024, 0.0037, 0.0049, 0.0061, 0.0073, 0.0085, 0.0097, 0.011, 0.0122, 0.0134, 0.0146, 0.0158, 0.017, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
import itertools
s = ['0.0000    0.0012    0.0024    0.0037    0.0049', '0.0061    0.0073    0.0085    0.0097    0.0110', '0.0122    0.0134    0.0146    0.0158    0.0170', '1.0000']
new_s = map(float, itertools.chain(*[re.split('\s+', i) for i in s]))
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0012, 0.0024, 0.0037, 0.0049, 0.0061, 0.0073, 0.0085, 0.0097, 0.011, 0.0122, 0.0134, 0.0146, 0.0158, 0.017, 1.0]
```

Comment: `itertools.chain(*` => `itertools.chain.from_iterable(`. Avoids the need for "*"

Answer (score 0):

Note that the list does not contain apostrophes and commas. These are part of the output to show that the list contains strings. The commas separate each string in the list and there is one apostrophe to show the beginning of the string and another to show the end of the string.

To manage the whitespace, you probably need to use `split()`. If you call this function on each string, you will get the individual string representations of the numbers. If you want numbers instead of strings, you need to convert them to `float`s. This will allow you to do numerical operations with the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['0.0000    0.0012    0.0024    0.0037    0.0049', '0.0061    0.0073    0.0085    0.0097    0.0110', '0.0122    0.0134    0.0146    0.0158    0.0170', '1.0000']
list_x = []

for i in x:
    list_x.append(i.split('    ')) # Erase 4 whitespaces, add values to a list.

list_final = [a for b in list_x for a in b] # Combine lists.
```